# In R: How do I run a multiple linear regression on interacted predictors without regressing on the variables not interacted?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, modeling

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to run a multiple linear regression with two predictors interacted without also regressing on the interacted predictors by themselves. Here is an example:

When I use this script to do a regression

```
lagfit <- lm(formula = Production ~ DayOfWeek*Employees, data = train)
```

It returns a regression with three predictors: day of week, # of employees, and the interaction. But I only want to regress on the interaction. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `:` operator instead of `*`:

```
lagfit <- lm(formula = Production ~ DayOfWeek:Employees, data = train)
```

Comment: Thanks! that was a simple solution. I'm a newb.

Comment: Technically correct, but are you sure you know what the meaning is? Check for example Frank Harrell's authoritative comments on the subject: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11009/including-the-interaction-but-not-the-main-effects-in-a-model